# Django see all user information in admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin, blogs, user-profile

After creating the member record in the application, only the username is reflected in the admin panel, but I want to get the name and surname as well. I specify this in the codes, but there is no reflection.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
   
    form=RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        name=form.cleaned_data.get("name")
        lastname=form.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
        username=form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password=form.cleaned_data.get("password")

       #newUser=User(name=name)
        newUser = User(username=username)  
        newUser.set_password(password)

        newUser.save()
        
        login(request,newUser)
        messages.info(request,"Başarıyla Kayıt Oldunuz...")
        return redirect("index")

    context={
            "form":form

        }
    return render(request,"register.html",context)
```

Form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
name=forms.CharField(max_length=50,label="Adı ")
lastname=forms.CharField(max_length=50,label="Soyadı ")
username=forms.CharField(max_length=50,label="Kullanıcı Adı ")
password=forms.CharField(max_length=20,label="Parola",widget=forms.PasswordInput)
confirm=forms.CharField(max_length=20,label="Parolayı Doğrula ",widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean(self):
    name=self.cleaned_data.get("name")
    lastname=self.cleaned_data.get("lastname")
    username=self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password=self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm=self.cleaned_data.get("confirm")

    if password and confirm and password != confirm:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Parolalar Eşleşmiyor...")

    values = {
        "name" : name,
        "lastname" :lastname,
        "username" : username,
        "password" :  password,
        
    }

    return values
```

Although I specify the name and name fields, it is not reflected in the panel

Comment: You're collecting the data, but you're not saving it into the user object in line `newUser = User(username=username)` or anywhere below it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to save?

Answer (score 0):

import user in form.py

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

pass the following below class Register form

````
class Meta:
         model= User
         fields=['']```
````

Comment: Do I have to write anything else besides this because nothing has changed?

Answer (score 0):

```
newUser = User(username=username, firstname=name, lastname=lastname)
```